# Libgdx AssetManager load multiple models at once

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm trying to use the asset manager to load my models async not to interrupt the rendering. I've made a custom file with vertices and indices (there are too many vertices for only one model). I'm trying to load this file using a custom loader in AssetManager. The loader looks like this:

```
public class MyLoader extends AsynchronousAssetLoader<Terrain, MyLoader.TerrainParameter> {

    private FileHandleResolver fileHandleResolver;

    public MyLoader(FileHandleResolver fileHandleResolver) {
        super(fileHandleResolver);
    }

    private Terrain terrain;

    @Override
    public Array<AssetDescriptor> getDependencies(String fileName, FileHandle file, TerrainParameter parameter) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAsync(AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, TerrainParameter parameter) {
        this.terrain = loadTerrain(file);

        List<CustomObject> terrainParts = terrain.getTerrainParts();

        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

        //-----Block of code-------
        for (CustomObject terrainPart: terrainParts) {
            modelBuilder.begin();
            MeshPartBuilder meshBuilder = modelBuilder.part("terrainPart", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position,
                    new Material());
            meshBuilder.addMesh(terrainPart.getVertices(), terrainPart.getIndices());
            Model terrainPartModel = modelBuilder.end();
            terrain.getTerrainPartModels().add(terrainPartModel);
        }
        //-----End Block of code-------
    }

    @Override
    public Terrain loadSync(AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, TerrainParameter parameter) {
        Terrain terrain = this.terrain;
        this.terrain = null;
        return terrain;
    }

    private Terrain loadTerrain(FileHandle fileHandle) {
          // Reading file here
    }


    public static class TerrainParameter extends AssetLoaderParameters<Terrain> {

    }
}
```

This doesn't work, when I render I get the following error:

```
08-18 18:58:19.933 31830-31862/com.pickaline.se E/emuglGLESv2_enc: device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glBufferData:427 GL error 0x502
08-18 18:58:19.933 31830-31862/com.pickaline.se D/emuglGLESv2_enc: sendVertexAttributes: bad offset / len!!!!!
08-18 18:58:19.933 31830-31862/com.pickaline.se A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 31862 (GLThread 423)

                                                    [ 08-18 18:58:19.934  1259: 1259 W/         ]
                                                    debuggerd: handling request: pid=31830 uid=10084 gid=10084 tid=31862
```

But if I move that exact same "Block of code" outside of my Loader it works flawlessly. Also if I only create the first Model inside the Loader that one is loaded correctly. Is there limitations on how much you can load async or on the ModelBuilder somehow? I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You cant do anything involving OpenGL function calls in the asynchronous thread, which includes instantiating Models, which create Meshes.

Comment: Okay, so there's no way to create large meshes without impact on the rendering thread?

Comment: You might be able to break up the steps so the actual Mesh instantiation happens in the synchronous part, but you prepare all the float[] geometry in the asynch part. I haven't done this...you'll need to look through the source of the classes you're using to see if it can be done.

Comment: That's pretty much what I already do, I create the float array and short array but the actual instantiating of the mesh is still time consuming and interrupts the gl thread. What surprises me is that it works to only create one model async but not more than that. Thanks for the feedback anyhow!